# Python: How to load in MATLAB strings and save them concatenated as a variable in a netCDF file?

Tags: python-3.x, string, matlab, netcdf4

I want to load in 2 string arrays from a MATLAB structure file, zip/concatenate them together, and then save into a netCDF file.

I have the following data MATLAB structure file:

data.string1 = ['a','b','c']

data.string2 = ['d','e','f']

In Python, I want to concatenate / zip them into a 2x3 matrix, and save them as variable 'text' in a netCDF file 'file.nc' with dimensions 'dim1' = 2, 'dim2' = 3.

This is what I have so far:

```
data f = h5py.File('data.mat','r') 

data = {"string1":np.str(f.get('string1')), "string2":np.array(f.get('string2'))}

dataset = Dataset('file.nc', 'w',  format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC') 

dim1 = dataset.createDimension('dim1', 2)
dim2 = dataset.createDimension('dim2', 3)
```

My problem is that strings 1 and 2 are classed as the following when loaded into Python and I am not sure how to proceed:

> HDF5 dataset "time_bounds_1": shape (1, 6), type "

How can I proceed to concatenate strings1, and 2, and save 'text' as a variable in the netCDF file with dimensions dim1 and dim2?

I also have the following code that could be adapted later to help:

```
text = dataset.createVariable('text', np.str, ('dim1','dim2')) # this does not work - error with np.str! 
text[:,:] = np.asmatrix(text) # not sure this will work with strings
```

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I decided to go down the route of creating the time lists in python, and then saving them as floating numbers in the netCDF rather than strings. It is not what I originally wanted but I have settled with this.

For those who may be interested, here is the Code (with different dimensions and variables to my simple example above):

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date,date2num
import datetime
# ----------------------
nv = 2
time=365
# ---------------------------------------------------
base = datetime.datetime(1950,1,1,00,00,1)
numdays = 365
timevalue1 = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
base = datetime.datetime(1950,1,1,23,59,59)
timevalue2 = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
#timevalue = datetime.datetime(2014,4,11,23,59)
time_unit_out= "days since 1950-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"
# ---------------------------------------------------
nc_out = Dataset('test.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
time = nc_out.createDimension('time',time)
nv = nc_out.createDimension('nv',nv)
times = nc_out.createVariable('time', np.float64, ('time','nv'))
times.setncattr('unit',time_unit_out);

times[:,0] = date2num(timevalue,time_unit_out);
times[:,1] = date2num(timevalue2,time_unit_out);

nc_out.close()
```